# ajax - Output not coming in a shorthand ajax code

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I have made a simple code for ajax to call a page but it does not seem to be working. can anyone tell me the error?

```
function toggledisp(val)
{
$.ajax({
  url: 'ads/xyz.php?a=' + val + '&b=2' ,
});
}
```

Also if we want to output the response text then how do we do so by using this method??

Comment: _"it does not seem to be working"_ - What _does_ it seem to be doing? E.g., is there an error in your console? The trailing comma at the end of your url string could prevent the code running if you're using IE (a point where for once I actually _agree_ with IE).

Comment: First, use a JS debugger to get the "first-aid", and when you can't solve after a few tries, then you can find help here.

Comment: I guess the syntax was wrong now it is working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function toggledisp(val)
{
  $.ajax({
    url: '/ads/xyz.php' ,
    data:{a:val,b:2},
    success:function(output){ alert(output); }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would highly recommened and invite you to take a look at **basic** ajax tutorial using jQuery

- [jQuery AJAX Tutorial, Example: Simplify Ajax development with jQuery](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/jquery-ajax-tutorial-example-ajax-jquery-development/)

> Also if we want to output the response text then how do we do so by
>   using this method??

You would use `success` or `complete` handler:

```
$.ajax({
  url:'url here',
  data: {foo:'foo', bar:'bar'}, // example of data you want to send 
  success: function(response) {
     alert(response);
  }
});
```

For more info, see above tutorial first.